# Is it possible to create a class ->Add, instance --> obj1 that can be called multiple times like the following : obj1(12)(34)(23)?

Tags: python, oop, addition, callable-object

I am new to python and trying to create a class named Add that will have a modified **call** to make its objects act like functions and be callable multiple times like the following:
class Adds:

```
#def __call__(self):
     #code for addition
```

`obj1 = Add(10) ---> should return 10 obj1(12)(10) ----> should return 22 obj1(12)10)(9) --->should return 31`

However, whatever I try to do the result will be " object not callable".
The point is how do we make an object callable in a way that it accepts more arguments in parenthesis as I mentioned above. ex : object(arg1)(arg2)...